# Laravel can't start php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

The error lies in the config/views.php, I changed it back to the original file. Thanks you all!!! The problem was this:
`'paths' => [
        array(__DIR__.'/../../public/views'),
    ],`

I was trying to render the view from the public folder. That is why I couldn't use `php artisan serve`. I changed it back to the original file and Icould use the command again.

I am using the newest version of Laravel 5.6. I am trying to make an api with AngularJs as front end.

When I am trying to serve with the command line, I get this error:
[image]

I have look up on google, but couldn't find the same senario. 
What could be the problem here?

This is on line 86 of the serviceprovider.php
[image]

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Response::json(Comment::get());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
//    public function create()
//    {
//        //
//    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        Comment::create(array(
            'author' => Input::get('author'),
            'text' => Input::get('text'),
        ));

        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Comment::destroy($id);

        return Response::json(array('success' => true));
    }
}
```

I don't have much information about this. So I am happy to hear about you're ideas.

Comment: What is the code on line 86 of the ServiceProvider.php?

Comment: do you have an exact version instead of 'latest' one ?

Comment: It seems that the `$namespace` variable is an array (and php tries to convert that to an string) what does the variable `$namespace` contain?

Comment: The namespace containes `Illuminate\support`

Comment: I was going to say, what files have you modified? Have you created any models? There is another issue similar where the `protected $tables` property was an array instead of a string like `protected $table = 'advisor_check';`

Comment: My model is empty

Comment: Yeah, but what have you changed/added to the system? Have to changed anything in the AppServiceProvider.php? trying to work out _where_ this is trying to load and throwing the error

Comment: I added something to the `webpack.mix.js` but when I delete it. I stil get the same error. Could it be something with the angularjs?

Comment: @MissesA  So when `$namespace = ['Illuminate\Support']` this should be `'Illuminate\Support'`  how is the method `loadsViewFromPath` called?

Comment: Also what does `$this->app->config['view']['paths']` contain maybe it's just a config mistake

Comment: This is core code, I think the issue lies in any controllers you have modified

Comment: The `loadsViewFromPath` isn't anywhere expect for in the `notificationserviceprovider` or `paginationprovider`.

Comment: The only controller I have is the `commentController`, I will show the code.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Do you have any views config?

Comment: I have this in my `config/views`, ` 'paths' => [
        array(__DIR__.'/../../public/views'),
    ],`

Comment: You javascript code will never -directly- trigger a conversion error in PHP..  I cannot find back the file in the exact way you wrote this in laravel 5.6.12.

Comment: Well `paths` is multidemensional array so in `foreach` `$viewPath` is array

Comment: That means it is somewhere in my controller or in the config file or somewhere else?

Comment: The error lies in the `config/views.php`, I changed it back to the original file. Thanks you all!!!

Comment: so, what code was different ?  It would be a good lesson to diff it..

Comment: I think `paths` config variable should be just a simple list (based on the comment above `'paths' => [ array(__DIR__.'/../../public/views'), ],`). Wrapping `array()` is reduntant

Comment: Because it is already an array?

Comment: I may be wrong. Just share what you changed to make it work